# php odbc_exec doesn't work unless I echo first?

Tags: php, ms-access, apache2, odbc

I am trying to query an access MDB file using php odbc_connect and odbc_exec. The idea is to return an array which I can then translate to json.

I am running php through apache2 on Ubuntu 12.10

Here is my code:

```
//Connect to the database
$conn=odbc_connect('stock-test','','');

//die if error
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
} 
//SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Stk_Items";

//This is the print command...see notes below for this
//print " "

//Execute SQL query
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

//If no result, there is an error in the SQL
if (!$rs) {
    exit("Error in SQL");
}

//Create an array to contain the results...
$arr = array();

//Loop through the results, pushing each array to the $arr array
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
    array_push($arr, $row);
}

print json_encode( $arr);


odbc_close($conn);
```

Now here is the strange thing. This code will only output the json if I print a blank space (or any other character) before the odbc_exec command is issued (I have commented out the command in the code above)

I have also run several other tests (echoing the results etc) but none will work unless I print some blank space before the odbc_exec command.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up a Virtual machine and reinstalled from scratch to see if the problem existed again on the new build. It didn't so it lead me to believe there was a problem with the build of Apache on the live machine. In the past few days I have removed and added Apache through the repositories and added all the latest updates through apt-get and the problem now appears to be resolved - very frustrated as the latest updates are normally applied so I can only imagine something must have gone wrong either with the initial install of apache2 or the php5-odbc.

Comment: +1 for the investigative work and the follow-up here. One thing I would check (for curiosity's sake, if nothing else) would be to inspect the `phpinfo()` results from each server to see if there are any apache2 `mod_`s or PHP extensions installed on the troublesome server that are absent from the clean install.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like an apache quirk to me. If you are using a web browser to trigger the PHP script and inspect the results then you really should be outputting at least `<html><body>` before anything else. If you want to see the results in a reasonably unmolested form you should echo a `<pre>` tag, too.

FWIW, I ran your code as-is from the command line and it worked fine for me.

Edit:

Further to comments below, this is indeed looking like an oddity when apache2 invokes a PHP script that uses `odbc_exec()`. To test, I created the following "page" on my Ubuntu 12.04 LAMP server...

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array('ID' => 1, 'text' => 'foo'), 
    array('ID' => 2, 'text' => 'bar'), 
    array('ID' => 3, 'text' => 'baz')
    );
print json_encode($arr);
```

...and Firefox does display the JSON string as follows...

[{"ID":1,"text":"foo"},{"ID":2,"text":"bar"},{"ID":3,"text":"baz"}]

...so apache2 has no problem spitting out a plain JSON string and Firefox has no problem displaying it.

Comment: Good call! I had been using different methods to connect to retrieve the json with similar results but I didn't think to rule apache out of the equation. I have run it from the command line and it worked for me as well. I do have other similar php scripts which query mysql and mssql and these run fine. Looks like a bug with apache2 which odbc_exec is triggering.

Comment: I should also add that I would usually add html and body tags but I just want to retrieve JSON only for an ajax call. Printing the blank character seems to kick it into action for the time being so I will make do for now.

Comment: @RichardGreen The fact that you can run your script from the command line and see the output suggests that `odbc_exec()` is working properly, but you just can't *see* the results in a browser window unless you echo a space first. That's more likely a result of the fact that what you are sending to the browser is not valid HTML, so the browser may not behave the way you think (hope) it will.

Comment: In my code, if you were to replace "print json_encode( $arr);" with "print_r($arr);" you will see that, without echoing the blank space first I do get output on the screen but it returns an empty array. With the blank space included, the array is then populated. I have also used other database methods which work fine in this situation. I have only found an issue when using the odbc_exec command in conjunction with Apache2.

Comment: I ran a quick test over the weekend in which I wrote a simple script to create a URL request to the server (so no browser involved) to retrieve the JSON and I got the same results. With the space, a full JSON object but without the space, an empty object was returned. It seems that when apache2 isn't in the mix, the odbc_exec command works fine. I am able to echo other information without having to use html tags and as I need to get a true JSON object back, the html tags should really be left off.

Comment: @RichardGreen Interesting, thanks for reporting back. Just curious: Did you by chance try `print "";` to see if just the invocation of `print` does something magic?

Comment: I have indeed Gord, but it seems that there needed to be a blank character to start the command properly.